# Django passing parameter from one funttion to another

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to pass the value from the drop down menu to the next function, but I get this error:

```
other_funtion() missing 1 required positional argument: 'descrip'
```

Python:

```py
def Home(request):
    # Description = menu_options.description()
    if env('ENVIRONMENT') == "TEST":
        current_user = f"{request.META['USERNAME']}" 
    else:
        current_user = request.META['REMOTE_USER']
    Description = Some_model.objects.raw("""  SELECT min(bgd.id) as id, groups, [Description]
        FROM [dbo].[description] bgd
        INNER JOIN  [dbo].[auth_group] ag
            ON bgd.groups= ag.[groups]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[auth_user_groups] aug
        ON ag.id = aug.group_id
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[auth_user] au
        on au.id = aug.[user_id]
        WHERE  bgd.Status= 'Active' AND au.[username]  = %s group by [Description], groups
        """,[current_user])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        descrip = request.session.get('Description')
        request.session['Description'] = descrip
        other_funtion(descrip)
        # request.session['Description'] = Description
        print(descrip)
        return  {"Description":Description}
    return render(request, "index.html",{"Description":Description})

def other_funtion(request):
       descrip = descrip 
       print(descrip)
return render(request, somehtml.html, {})
```

HTML:

```html
                     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        {% for results in Description %}
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'BidderPref' %}" target="_self name="descript"
                            value="{{results.Description}}">{{results.Description}}
                        </a>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
```

Expected the value to pass if I change the section in the opening funtion to still have the issue

```py
def other_funtion(request, descrip)
```

I also tried using

```py
descrip = request.session['Description'] #in the section funtion is try similar with the class
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it removed section from the first function all but the query.

In the HTML:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'BidderPref'%}?id={{results.id}}" 
 target="_self" name="descript" value="{{results.Description}}"
 {{results.Description}}</a>
```

Second function:

```
descrip = request.GET.get('id')
```